# Where does .available method come from?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I was going through this simple, short tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4CXB5y_eJDk) on jQuery & Ajax when I came to one line of code I don't understand. In the very short video it's line 13 in main.js. The line is `if(data.available !== undefined)`.

My question is, where the heck does the `.available` method come from? This isn't explained in the tutorial/video, & it comes out of the blue as far as I'm concerned. Is it jQuery? Is it Ajax? Where does it come from? I'm assuming it's Ajax but I can't find any documentation on it. Any help is greatly appreciated. . .Here's the full Ajax code. . .

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'check/username.php',
        type: 'get',
        data: {
            username: target.val()
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            if(data.available !== undefined){
                //defined
            }else {

            }
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('Error');
        }

  });
});
```

Comment: https://youtu.be/4CXB5y_eJDk?t=102

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `check/username.php` returns JSON data. That JSON string has a property named `available`.

For example the JSON might come back with a string like this:

```
{ 
  name : "Chris", 
  available : "true"
}
```

In your AJAX handler, you could access any of these properties, for example:

```
success: function(data){
  if(data.available !== undefined){
    alert(data.name);
  }
}
```

The data doesn't come "out of the blue" it is what is returned by the AJAX call.

Comment: I know where the data comes from, it was just the available property I didn't understand. . .So, it's a Json property?

Comment: Never mind the last comment Dave, I see now, lol So easy & I didn't see it. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`data` is what is returned from `username.php`.  The JSON object returned is automatically parsed, so `available` would be a property on the object returned.

For example, `username.php` probably returns something like:

```
{
  "available": true
}
```

Comment: I get where data comes from. What I don't get is the available property. Where does this come from? Is it an Ajax property? And thanks for your answer, Brad.

Comment: @ChrisKavanagh I don't know what you mean by "AJAX property", but that `available` property *is* part of the data returned.  `data` is just the data returned.

Comment: Available has to come from somewhere. In Python (as most lang) there's a len property. Well, I know that comes from Python if I see it in a file. What language is the available prop a part of?

Comment: @ChrisKavanagh `available` comes from your data.  I don't know how else to phrase this to you.  Your data contains an `available` property.  Your data isn't a string, it's JSON that is parsed into a real object.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it now Brad. It's just a property he's written into the JSON file. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @ChrisKavanagh Yes!  Exactly.